# Use msg.value more than once vs assign a variable?

Tags: solidity, transactions, wallet-transfer

Imagine that I have an Smart Contract which is using the uint value of msg.value to add it to other "not monetary" variable, only to record the received money. I'm a bit worried specially for security concerns, I don't want to have a breach that could lead to money loss.

My biggest doubt is if msg.value is more than a uint, and could have potential issues if you use it directly for anything apart of value transfers.

```
struct Item {
    uint _postId;
    address payable _author;
    uint _value;        
}

uint numPosts;

mapping(uint => Item) items;
uint[] public itemValues;
mapping(uint => address payable) itemAuthors;
```

**Is this valid?**

```
    function supportAuthor(uint _itemId) payable public  {
       //Monetary transfer here
       address payable author_ = itemAuthors[_itemId];
       require(author_ == address(author_),"Invalid address"); 
       author_.transfer(msg.value); 
       
       //adding the received money to the struct
       items[_itemId]._value = items[_itemId]._value + msg.value;
       
       //adding the received money to the list of items. 
       //Array position is the ID.
       itemValues[_itemId] = itemValues[_itemId] + msg.value;
    }
```

**Or is better in this way?** **- Assigning msg.value to uint variable**

```
    function supportAuthor(uint _itemId) payable public  {
       uint value = msg.value;
       //Monetary transfer here
       address payable author_ = itemAuthors[_itemId];
       require(author_ == address(author_),"Invalid address"); 
       author_.transfer(msg.value); 
       
       //adding the received money to the struct
       items[_itemId]._value = items[_itemId]._value + value;
       
       //adding the received money to the list of items. 
       //Array position is the ID.
       itemValues[_itemId] = itemValues[_itemId] + value;
    }
```

Comment: Same...................

Comment: You may want to use SafeMath in your arithmetic operations though (e.g., replace `+ x` with `.add(x)`).

Comment: You also wanna call `transfer` as the very last operation in your function, [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.12/security-considerations.html#re-entrancy) is why.

Comment: Consider the last two comments as a (free of charge) security audit for your code.

Comment: And `require(author_ == address(author_),"Invalid address");` is redundant BTW.

Comment: I want to make sure that a valid address has been found.

Comment: Nevertheless, since `author_ == address(author_)` is always true, this statement is redundant.

Comment: I understand your point, but imagine thar provided ID returns an empty value, and not an address value.

Comment: You're missing a fundamental point about mappings. No such thing "empty value". A `mapping` variable maps **every possible** key to a value. By default, all keys are mapped to the zero value of the mapped type. For example, in `mapping (address => bool) x`, all possible addresses are initially mapped to `false`, and in `mapping (uint256 => address) y`, all possible uint256 values are initially mapped to `0x000...000` (the zero address). See [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.12/types.html#mapping-types).

Comment: What about checking if: itemAuthors[_itemId] != address(0)

Comment: Yes, you should definite do that.